# How to display a unsorted list using PDO on SQLite table?

Tags: php, sqlite

I try to display a results of a SELECT query using PDO in a unsorted list and for that I use this code:

```
<?php
  try {
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:db/MyDatabase.db');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT genus, species FROM MyTable ORDER BY genus ASC, species ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
    echo '<ul>' . '<li>' . $data . '<br/>' . '</li>' . '</ul>';
}
  catch(PDOException $e) {echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();}
  $conn = null;
?>
```

But I only get displayed the first item of the column "genus".
How can I get a unsorted list in a more friendlier form of "**genus** (space) **species**"?

Comment: [ask] [mre] [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Comment: As you only retrieve one column in `fetchColumn`, that might be the issue. You could use `fetchAll()` and then iterate through the array, or just use `fetch()` inside a loop to retrieve all rows. Use `var_dump($data);` inside that loop to see what format the data is returned in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchColumn()` only returns the first column from a result set `fetchAll()` will return all rows from a table. Then loop through the array using `foreach` or `while`.

Trying to echo `$data` will not work since you cannot echo an array, you would need to specify the array keys which in this case would be the column names.

```php
<?php
  try {
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:db/MyDatabase.db');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT genus, species FROM MyTable ORDER BY genus ASC, species ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<ul>';
    if ( !empty($data) ) {
      foreach ( $data as $row ){
         echo '<li>'. $row['genus'] .' '. $row['species'] .'</li>';
      }
    } else {
      // something to show when no results.
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: it returns to me: Notice: Undefined index: genus [...]  Notice: Undefined index: species  [...] in line 11. And printing out only the first bullet from the list. My knowledge is very basic, so, any help is welcome.

Comment: @SzabolcsHorvath forgot to change $data to $row, try now.

Comment: Thank you, For this one I should used my head. I dont  know why i thought about something more difficult.